# Signing in two users at the same time on the same device (Parse BE)

Tags: android, parse-platform

A project I am working on requires two users to sign onto the app at the same time. The app would not have functionality or start the MainActivity until *both* users are successfully signed in. I am wondering if it is possible, and if not, what kind of code-magic can either simulate this, or provide some sort of work around.

At the moment I'm thinking of having both users sign into the app on their own phones, then "connecting" both of their accounts creating an object with their information, and then deactivating the functionality on one phone, and starting MainActivity on the other.

It seems like there might be a more efficient way, but at the moment it escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply sign in first user, then save his objectId and log out him.
Then do same with next user.

Next if you would like to get some info about one user, you can get `ParseObject` / `ParseUser` by query

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground("a23sd1wq", new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot have two log in users on the same device. If users have to notify each other when they log in, you would benefit from implementing a persistent connection model using providers like PubNub